# Selecting specific elements in R for cor()

Tags: r, parameters, correlation

I'm in a situation where I need to find the correlation between two variables `cor(dataframe$x,dataframe$y)`, where `x, y` are column names and `dataframe` is a dataframe. One of the columns in my dataframe is an indicator function (0's and 1's).

I'm wondering how I can compare values of x and their corresponding values of y for two separate groups (0's and 1's). I'm new to R, so I guess I'm wondering if there's built in functionality into the `cor()` function, or if I have to reconstruct a dataframe/array with `x's` and `y's` to find the correlations for separate groups.

Guess that also leads to another question (which I've googled, it's not very clear cut to me yet): what's the difference between using a vector, array and dataframe in R under these functions (i.e. `cor()`, `t.test()`, etc.)?

Comment: You probably mean `dataframe$x` and `dataframe$y`

Comment: Oh, right - typo there. Yeah, I do. Other than that though, do you know how I might resolve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compute the correlation on the subset of rows specified by the indicator column. To select a subset use `dataframe[logical_index,]` where `logical_index` is a vector of booleans (in R called logical). To do this you should convert the indicators to booleans.

```
logical_index <- as.logical(dataframe$indicator)
cor(dataframe[logical_index,]$x, dataframe[logical_index,]$y)
cor(dataframe[!logical_index,]$x, dataframe[!logical_index,]$y)
```

Vectors, matrixes, arrays, lists and data frames are all different primitive types of R. A clear and relative easy introduction to the differences is given by Hadley in Advanced R: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html

Comment: Done - I've converted `indicator` to TRUE and FALSE values. Just to confirm, the `cor()` code you listed gives the correlation of `x` and `y` two times: once for **only** `TRUE` values and once for **only** `FALSE` values.

Comment: That is right. The first call gives the correlation for the rows where the `indicator` column is `TRUE`. The second call gives the correlation for the rows where the `indicator` column is `FALSE`.

Comment: Fantastic - thanks a lot! When I do the calls though, I'm not getting an output as detailed as I usually get (the output of which I've added to the original post). Any reason why?

Comment: The output you posted is the result of a call to `cor.test()`, but not a call to `cor()`. `cor()` just gives a correlation matrix, while `cor.test()` provides a statistical test of the correlation.

Comment: @Noah Ah, got it. But the value for the correlation of both `cor.test()` and `cor()` would be the same under input of the same two sets, yes?